empty non-Vega Deneb template
I would like to create a donut chart with patterning instead of color. As far as I know, patterns can't be used with Vega or Vega lite templates and there are no other donut templates that I've found (I've seen the ring and ring donut KPI, but couldn't figure out how to customize them for my purposes). How can I just start out with an "existing" empty non-Vega template so I can try to build it from there?

OK, I've attempted to work from the EnterpriseDNA Donut KPI template, adding the first ring (Warehouse Sales) to the second (Distribution Sales) in the same visual. I have JSON code that's apparently too long to enter here. I set the 2nd theta to start at the 1st, but it's only showing one of the rings.

My code is here: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DENEB-and-Power-BI-Enthusiasts/gh-p/DENEBandPowerBIEnthusiasts

Start with the Vega-lite Donut example from here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/arc_donut.html
If you don't know how to get that sample to work in Deneb, check out my guide in this presentation: Deneb Custom Visual in Power BI.pptx
Then to adjust that spec to use patterns, see the Deneb doc here: https://deneb-viz.github.io/pattern-fills
This is a Deneb feature, so you won't find this in the Vega doc. Also make sure the Deneb Settings are using the SVG render mode.

The gist of it is you'll use predefined pattern names like this fill:
{
  "data": { "name": "dataset" },
  "mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "fill": "url(#diagonal-stripe-1)"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Country",
      "type": "nominal"
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "$ Sales",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
}

See the doc for the list of pattern names and for how to adjust colors and intensity:

